How to solve flickering issue during first render?
I’m new to React and am building a React application with a canvas where SVG elements can be dragged. The logic seems fine, but there’s a flickering issue during the first render. How can I solve this?

Another issue is that I want the rect to be randomly positioned on the canvas when it’s initialized, but if I use
const { isGrabbing, position, dragRef } = useDrag<SVGRectElement>({
  x: Math.random() * 800,
  y: Math.random() * 800,
});

Next.js throws a Hydration error. What is correct way?
Here is the full code:
// Canvas.tsx
"use client";

import { useRef } from "react";
import { useDrag } from "@/hooks";

export default function Canvas() {
  const containerRef = useRef<SVGSVGElement | null>(null);

  const { isGrabbing, position, dragRef } = useDrag<SVGRectElement>({
    x: Math.random() * 800,
    y: Math.random() * 800,
  });

  return (
    <div className="flex min-h-screen items-center justify-center">
      <svg
        ref={containerRef}
        viewBox="0 0 800 800"
        className="relative h-[800px] w-[800px] bg-white"
      >
        <rect
          ref={dragRef}
          x={position.x}
          y={position.y}
          width={100}
          height={100}
          fill="red"
          className={isGrabbing ? "cursor-grabbing" : "cursor-grab"}
        />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}

// hooks/useDrag.ts
import { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

interface Position {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

export default function useDrag<T extends SVGGraphicsElement>(
  initialPosition: Position = { x: 0, y: 0 },
) {
  const [isGrabbing, setIsGrabbing] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState<Position>(initialPosition);
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState<Position>({ x: 0, y: 0 });

  const dragRef = useRef<T | null>(null);

  // change the position
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setPosition({ x: 100, y: 200 });
  }, []);

  // listen to the pointer down event
  useEffect(() => {
    const handlePointerDown = (e: PointerEvent) => {
      setIsGrabbing(true);
      setOffset({
        x: e.clientX - position.x,
        y: e.clientY - position.y,
      });
    };

    const dragEle = dragRef.current;
    dragEle?.addEventListener("pointerdown", handlePointerDown);

    return () => {
      dragEle?.removeEventListener("pointerdown", handlePointerDown);
    };
  }, [position]);

  // listen to the pointer move and up event
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isGrabbing) {
      const handlePointerMove = (e: PointerEvent) => {
        setPosition({
          x: e.clientX - offset.x,
          y: e.clientY - offset.y,
        });
      };

      const handlePointerUp = () => {
        setIsGrabbing(false);
      };

      document.addEventListener("pointermove", handlePointerMove);
      document.addEventListener("pointerup", handlePointerUp);

      return () => {
        document.removeEventListener("pointermove", handlePointerMove);
        document.removeEventListener("pointerup", handlePointerUp);
      };
    }
  }, [isGrabbing, offset]);

  return {
    isGrabbing,
    position,
    dragRef,
  };
}

Check out this codesanbox link.
Just focus on app/page.tsx and hooks/useDrag.
I want to solve the flickering issue and randomly place the rect on the canvas during initialization.

been a while since I've used react, but flickering should be because of client side rendering. If you want to avoid that can render on server but need some server side impl of canvas which may be too much. Alternatively you can hide it until ready. About the hydration error not sure but if you show the error it's helpful. If you make a  codesandbox or something can have a better look

^ Yes. I have created a codesanbox. You can check it out above.

okay nice thanks, well for the hydration error, would say it's calculating on server then client, but random will be different on each one so probably want to make nullable or something and run the random set in an effect so it only runs client, seems simple solution for that

I think the simplest way to just solve the issues you are experiencing are to

not render the canvas until loaded
only run the randomization of position on the client.

Just tried it out, if you return setPosition from useDrag.
Then you can do
  const { isGrabbing, position, setPosition, dragRef } =
    useDrag<SVGRectElement>();

  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoaded(true);
    setPosition({
      x: Math.random() * 800,
      y: Math.random() * 800,
    });
  }, []);

so call useDrag without args, then in the effect you set the random positions, and you can also set a loaded flag to true.
then if not loaded
  if (loaded===false) {
    return null;
  }

You can see on https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/jvgzs9?embed=1
Honestly, don't know why you'd get the hydration error if using "use client" though, that's around the time I stopped using react and next, in part due to that, think it's confusing and all over the place, but hopefully someone else can provide more insights.
